# Grouping a Stream twice

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a Collection of String arrays looking like this

```
new ArrayList<>().addAll(
    Arrays.asList(
        new String[]{"foo","bar", "5"}, 
        new String[]{"foo", "bar2", "8"},  
        new String[]{"foo", "bar", "5"}
    )
);
```

, and I want to group this list producing a `Map<String, Map<String, Double>>` giving a result similar to this

```
[
  {
    key:"foo",
    value: [
      {
        key: "bar",
        value: 10
      },
      {
        key: "bar2",
        value: 8
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

After that the internal value will be a sum of the third column in the array.

Trying to do this on my own I've came up with the following code:

```
 Function<String[], String> teste = (row -> row[finalCategoriaColumnIndex]);
 Function<String[], String> teste2 = (row -> row[3]);
 ToDoubleFunction<String[]> teste3 = (row -> (row -> Double.parseDouble(row[finalValorColumnIndex]));



sqlResult
    .getResults()
    .parallelStream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        teste,
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            teste2,
            Collectors.summingDouble(teste3)
        )
     ));
```

But IntelliJ accuse an error, what can I do?

EDIT:
IntelliJ error

    `(java.util.stream.Collector<? super java.lang.String,A,R>)
in Stream cannot be applied
to
(java.util.stream.Collector<java.lang.String[],capture<?>,java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Double>>>)`

Comment: What is an error then?

Comment: Believe IntelliJ.  Post the error message you get; perhaps that will be clearer.  Your example is hard to follow for me.  That might explain why you're having trouble.

Comment: Also, why do you have parallelStream on SqlResult.Headers? Are there really such huge amount of headers that it's reasonable to inialize the whole parallel processing harness to compute a sum of double?

Comment: Sorry, i'm going to iterate the results, my mistake

Comment: Works fine for me, assuming that `parallelStream()` returns a `Stream<String[]>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the getHeaders(), should be getResults(). I think I need a cup of coffe, thank you for the answers